# Insect identification - Oregon

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hemiptera

Western Cascade forest, in a small clearing in the grasses. Possibly related to leafhoppers? Looks a little bit similar, and it was able to jump quite well. The last pair of legs are arranged the same exact way as leafhoppers. Assuming it's within Hemiptera. I've never seen one before.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Possibly related to leafhoppers? .. Assuming it's within Hemiptera.

Your assumptions are correct! This insect *is* related to leafhoppers, in that it's a [planthopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planthopper), and, is of the order [Hemiptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera) -- it belongs to the species *Scolops sulcipes*.

According to the College of Agriculture & Natural Resources at the University of Delaware, this is one of eight species in Oregon that belong to the [Dictyopharidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictyopharidae) family. ([source](http://ag.udel.edu/research/planthoppers/families/dictyopharidae.html))

[image]

[image]